# How to share current browser(webdriver) object in new python keyword files

Tags: python, robotframework

I use below code but it returns : RuntimeError('No browser is open')

```
class UtilityFunction(ExtendedSelenium2Library):
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'

    def __init__(self):
        # super.__init__()
        self.lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('ExtendedSelenium2Library')
        self.driver=self.lib._current_browser()
```

Answer (score 3):

The code in the `__init__()` is ran when an object is initialized - in Robot Framework that happens when the library is imported (in the beginning of the file). At that point, there is no opened browser - you still haven't ran the suite setup, the keyword `Open Browser` hasn't been ran; thus the exception.

The "fix" is not to get an instance of the webdriver in the constructor:

```
def __init__(self):
    # super.__init__()
    self.lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('ExtendedSelenium2Library')
    self._driver = None  # internal attribute, don't use it in the methods, but "self.driver"

@property
def driver(self):
    if self._driver is None:
        self._driver=self.lib._current_browser()
    return self._driver

@driver.setter
def driver(self, custom):
    self._driver=custom
```

This approach is using [class properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=class%20property#property) - automatic getter and setters; when your code uses `self.driver`, if it's value is not defined (still `None`), it will automatically be assigned to the return of `self.lib._current_browser()`.

Comment: It would be even more convenient to make `self.driver` a property.